# In Anylogic , I want to store n "Product" that have been sorted using the switch statement, and then use AGV to move them

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I want to store n "Product" that have been sorted using the switch statement, and then use AGV to move them.
However, when the first "Product" enters the Batch block, conveyor stops moving.
Is it possible to specify the number of products to be stored in each node from A1 to C3 in a batch?

Many thanks.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q10z5.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSiF2.png)

Answer (score 0):

#### Independent batching

Do you want to batch independently for each node?

If so, you should `"agentify" your node process flow. For each node, create an AgentType` MyNode`, store the actual node using a parameter and create a batch process flow with` Enter`and`Exit`blocks. In your main flow, send products to the respective`MyNode`agent using an`Exit` flow block.

If this is too hard, check some example models and the AnyLogic YouTube channel, some good resources there to learn this powerful OOP technique.

#### dynamic batch size

If I understood wrong, then maybe this will help (i.e. you do not want to batch independently but simply change the batch size dynamically):

Similar to your `getTargetNode`, you can create a function `getBatchSize` which returns an integer based on an argument of type `Node`, name it `argNode`. In it, you can write some code similar to

```
if argNode.equals(A1) {
    return X; // whatever batch size needed for node A1
else if... // for other nodes
```

Probably, `argNode` would be your `targetNode` but it is not clear from your screens.

Comment: >Benjamin
Thanks to your kind instruction.
I tried the "dynamic batch size" method, but still the conveyor stopped when the first "Product" arrived at the targetNode... (I've added a picture.)
I will try to solve the problem myself, but if you have any advice, I would really appreciate it. Thank you